# Codeigniter: Redirect guest under certain url and after

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am not sure what exact term for it but what I am trying to do is to redirect all guest if they are on `admin/` or any url after `admin/dashboard/` or admin/posts/new/` etc.. no matter how deep segments are there.

I have written helper to redirect guest `guest_redirect()` to the login screen and working find without any issue but just want to do above stuff so I don't have to check on every controller below `admin/`

**Note:** I am using HMVC so all controllers extends `MX_Controller`

### **EDIT:**

I have tried below code in `MX_Controller` class `__construct()` and it is working fine

```
if($this->uri->segment(1) === 'admin'){
    guest_redirect();
}
```

It is redirecting all url under `admin/` to the login screen. Just wonder if it is good practice to modify core `MX_Controller` class or there is any other way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a credentials system.
You can use an array in the session or a table in the db, with the users and their credentials.

You can check if the user has the credential and then permit the access or redirect him/her to other controller.

Edit:
You can use $this->router->class to know the name of the controller where you are.

```
if ($this->router->class == "admin") {
  guest_redirect();
}
```

You can use $this->router->method too, this returns the name of the method where you are.

Comment: I am already using Ion Auth for that and the helper is containing that to perform check whether user is logged in or not if not than it is redirecting to the login screen. So the problem is not that but the right way to redirect user from `admin/` and under `admin/` uri

Comment: Edited my answer to add a new possible solution.